# Is there a way I can get the name of an emoji from its character as a string?

Tags: javascript, emoji

I'm working in javascript (in the browser not nodejs) and I want to be able to take an emoji character (something like ) and grab a description or name for it (like face with raised eyebrow). This data seems to be available in some form in [Unicode's full list of emojis](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) but I'd like to know if there is some kind of way to fetch this data automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: You can ingest it from [cldr](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr). The [annotations directory](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/tree/main/common/annotations) contains readable names for text-to-speech purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been searching for this and found [Open Emoji Api](https://emoji-api.com/). Probably it'll be helpful for your use case.

**Example usage:**

```js
const emoji = "";
const key = "20fa1d1b04d5a670f8f7a0d1ace322c0d49f9012";
fetch(`https://emoji-api.com/emojis?search=${emoji}&access_key=${key}`)
  .then(e => e.json())
  .then(e => {
    console.log(emoji, e[0].unicodeName);
  })
```

**Working API keys**
If you don't want to give out your own email, I used a temp one to create these keys:

- `20fa1d1b04d5a670f8f7a0d1ace322c0d49f9012`
- `ec07ff80043b910ad20772b199f7bf256815e17a`
- `934d90059eef84fdd74bf104380b56837025f187`
- `0c180627af50c8ab3fef62731790c9ea4a407d5f`